# Whose job is to check if the passenger has a valid visa to the destination he is travelling to?

Tags: visas, air-travel, legal, airlines, airport-security

Is it the airport security at the country you flying from? I highly doubt it because I have been to countries where it's so corrupted that you buy the airport officials for the price of a dinner.

Is it the aircrew' responsibility? Again I don't think they care much - unless there is severe punishments - in corrupted third world countries.

I have been personally in a situation when an officer at a certain airport insisted on examining my British passport before he allowed me to move to the gate because I refused to slip him a $100 note. I was travelling to the UK yet I have another passport which is valid and it is issued by the country I was flying from, which means he had no reason whatsoever - nor I think he cared - to examine my British passport to check if it's valid.

**Edit** to summarize it, I want to expose as little as possible of information about my dual nationality. For that I need to know whom I am obligated to show my passport(s)

Comment: @pnuts I think my question has inspired him, or maybe I can predict the future.

Comment: You are confusing many things. The airline is supposed to check and can be fined if they don't. Depending on local consumer laws and their terms of carriage, they might also very well be entitled to demand to see a passport or deny boarding but that's not *per se* a consequence of their being “responsible” for anything. And it doesn't mean the destination country won't check again, which makes corruption less of an issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the end of the day it is your responsibility to make sure that you have the required Visas/etc for the country you are travelling to.

However it is the airlines responsibility to check that you at least appear to meet the required entry requirements, which would include having a visa for the country, or a passport from a country that does not require a visa.  If the airline allows you to fly to a country without such documents, then in most cases the airline will be fined by the country you have arrived in.

Your comment that the airline staff refused to let you proceed because you didn't "slip him a $100 note" shows complete ignorance on your behalf, and is insulting to the airline staff involved.  They were doing their job, as required by the country you were flying to.  They DID have a valid reason to examine your passport, and they certainly DID care that it was valid.

Comment: I am not offended by your comment cause it looks like you have never been to a corrupted country, the man ASKED me for money to fasten the process. Do I have to name the country?

Comment: In certain countries (at least one as my personal experience) some officers at the exit airport area ask directly some money in order to let you out during the passport check.

Comment: @Doc Corruption happens in some places

Comment: @pnuts I do, I care about my anonymity, SE Travel users wanted to come after my gold bar when I accidentally revealed some details. Anyway it's on [these countries](http://www.cheatsheet.com/business/7-most-corrupt-countries.html/?a=viewall)

Comment: @User Ultimately if you are in a country that is as corrupted as you allude to, then the question of "whose job is it" is broad.  There is the internationally accepted responsible party which is the airline staff and there is the locally accepted practice of officials lined up for bribes and in many countries there are rules that allow law enforcement or officials wider ranges of questioning powers.

Comment: The way your question reads, you had the option to either show him your passport (as is REQUIRED by the airline) OR "slip him $100".  It sounds to me more like you caused the option of the bribe to come up - presuming you were willing to show your UK passport there would have been absolutely no reason for you to bribe him for anything!  I'm guessing you refused, and he gave you an "option".